# How to Read Data from OBDII in Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, obd-ii

I need a way to connect data from Bluetooth using Ionic 3 to retrieve data.

I now use the code as an example:

```
this.bluetoothSerial.write(this.code).then( (success) => {
    alert('Connected ' + '. Data reading is successful: ' + new Uint8Array(success));
},
```

Comment: What's the problem with that code?

Comment: Yes, I run this code but can not to get data. Is there another way?

Comment: Hi Teera, welcome to SO! Please bear in mind the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and especially the ["MCVE"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) portion, as we are not able to troubleshoot your problem without more information from you. Good luck!